# cron fires callback function immediately instead of at designated time

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, cron, cron-task

I'm defining a cron job and giving it a callback function to send emails.  However, instead of firing at the specified time, it fires immediately when my application is run and fails to fire at the specified time given.  Is there something wrong with my cron expression? I wanted it to fire at 9:42 pm to test it.  The idea is to have this function fire at the same time everyday.

Relevant coffeescript code:

```
cron = require 'cron'
...
cronJob = cron.job('0 42 21 * * *', sendEmails())
cronJob.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're calling `sendEmails` when you call `cron.job` when you're supposed to be giving `cron.job` a reference to the function. The parentheses on `sendEmails` in here:

```
cron.job('0 42 21 * * *', sendEmails())
# ----------------------------------^^
```

call the function. You want to say:

```
cron.job('0 42 21 * * *', sendEmails)
```

Comment: Gotcha, I'm new to coffeescript so I thought I needed that for syntactical reasons, but this makes more sense.  Unfortunately, it still does not work.  It won't send an email at the time I designate.

Comment: Any error messages anywhere? Isn't `cron = requre 'cron'`  really `cron = require 'cron'`?

Comment: No error messages, and it is `cron = require 'cron'`, that was just a typo above.  I edited my original post.

Comment: I am running my app in Ubuntu, but Ubuntu is running in a VM.  I wouldn't think this would affect anything, but I thought I'd share this as it could make a difference.

Comment: I figured it out, I was basing my test times off of my computer's clock when my VM's clock was set to a different time.  It's the little things that always get you.  I accepted your answer, mu is too short, because that was also an issue I was having.

Comment: Cool. I'm sure we'd eventually have gotten to the "is the clock right?" question but better sooner than later :)